# php count month quantity with difference less than 30 days

Tags: php, date, datediff

I need to get difference between months, independently of days.
if i do this:

```
$todaStart = new DateTime("2015-06-30");
$dateEnd = new DateTime("2015-07-01");

$diff = $todaStart->diff($dateEnd);
var_dump($diff);

object(DateInterval)[3]
public 'y' => int 0
public 'm' => int 0
public 'd' => int 1
public 'h' => int 0
public 'i' => int 0
public 's' => int 0
[...]
```

the "m" parameter is 0, but the month changed, so for the counts that i need to do, i need that the result be 1

The same happens if i change the month to "08", it should count 2 month difference, but the response come as 1 month.

Comment: Your question asks for the difference in days which is exactly what your code is giving you. The fact that the month happened to change also does not matter. To have 'm' be a value of 1 in this case would be incorrect.

Is there other logic that relies on the month containing a value of 1? Perhaps the other logic is flawed and needs to be reworked.

Comment: Title and question content are contradictory, "independently of days." vs "less than 30 days".

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I missed something in the time to translate. already edited the question. i need to calculate a FEE for a product, the client pay as a quantity of late months.
They have until the last day of the month, on day one of the next month already count as one month late.

Comment: @CharlieEgan like, if is to "concatenated" months like january and february from 2015-01-25 to 2015-02-05 is less than 30 days, if you go to  2015-01-25 to 2015-03-05 if you sum the days and divide for 2 (the number of months) each month will have less than 30~31(full-month) days.

Comment: Please explain more : The same happens if i change the mount to "08", it should count 2 month difference, but the response come as 1 month.

Comment: @Monty sorry, i meant month, read a lot of times and even pasted on google translate and still got some mistakes

Comment: but response comes in 1 month ???? Not getting

Comment: @Monty `$expiredDate = new DateTime("2015-06-30");
$today = new DateTime("2015-08-01");
var_dump($todaStart->diff($dateEnd));
public 'm' => int 1
  public 'd' => int 2`
the subscription for this client ended in 2015-06-30, so month 7 he is one month late, month 8 he is two months late.
so he has to pay 2 months times my FEE

Comment: If you are counting like this then just get months from two different dates and subtract them. Eg : date one 2015-06-30 date two 2015-08-01. Get only months like 06 and 08. difference is 2. This is your answer

Comment: @Monty and if i get 2015-12-30 and 2016-01-01? =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging on the web i found on [this](http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/12/calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-php#.VpjQU1I6w0x) site this solution, hope it help others.

```
 $d1= new DateTime("2015-06-01");
 $d2= new DateTime("2015-07-30");

 $y1 = $d1->format('Y');
 $m1 = $d1->format('m');
 $y2 = $d2->format('Y');
 $m2 = $d2->format('m');

 $diff = (($y2 - $y1) * 12) + ($m2 - $m1);
 // var_dump($diff) output 1
```